# Talent or knack

Tags: word-choice, connotation

I'd like to ask the connotations they have when we say :

> She has a **talent** for singing/ playing football/ acting/ painting
>   etc.
>
> She has a **knack** for singing/ playing football/ acting/ painting
>   etc.

---

Definitions by Oxford Dictionary

Talent : A natural ability to do something well

Knack  : A special skill or ability that you have naturally or **can learn**

Comment: A *talent* is large, sweeping; a *knack* is small, focused, sometimes odd or interesting but useless (like a *parlor trick*).

Comment: Would it be odd or disdaining to use the word knack for someone's singing

Comment: It's much more common to describe singing, on the whole, as a *talent* (in fact, it is a classic example of a talent!), but you could say she has a *knack for singing*, if it pleases you. It'd be more idiomatic to describe something smaller, and possible odder, as a *knack*, such as, perhaps, *she has a knack for karaoke*.

Comment: She has a knack for saying just the right thing / knitting little bootees / playing a piece of music everyone will like / buying presents the grandchildren really like ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Knack](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/knack) can have several meanings. The most common implies an ordinary person with no particular training that happens to be particularly good at a certain activity. A similar meaning is that the person can learn that activity quicker than normal. These two definitions are closely related to 'talented' as they both deal with natural ability. However, [talented](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/talented) often implies they already have some degree of expertise.

*After starting to take piano lessons, Joe found that he had a knack for music and was soon playing complex pieces.*

*John is such a talented musician that he can play a song after hearing it once on the radio.*

---

An alternate connotation of knack implies a tendency based on sheer luck. While using 'talent' here could get your meaning across, 'knack' is preferable. 

*Susie had a knack for picking the winners of the horse race, even though she just picked the horses with cute names*